# Does the US allow applying for visas on two different passports

Tags: visas, usa, passports

I have two passports (neither of which is a US one). I plan to apply for a US work visa using one of my passports, and then apply for a US travel visa using the other passport. Is this allowed? I want to use two different passports because it is easier to get a US work visa on passport A, and it is easier to use passport B when travelling from one of the countries I want to visit.

Comment: Which work visa category?  I don't know whether it makes a difference, but it might.

Comment: @phoog TN visa.

Comment: In that case we can infer that one passport is Mexican and the other is neither Canadian nor eligible for the visa waiver program.  If that inference is incorrect then you don't actually have a problem.  This is especially true if you have a Canadian passport because in that case you don't need an actual visa affixed to your passport, you just show up at the border and apply for admission.  Are you planning to visit the US as a tourist before moving there for work?  If you enter the US with a B visa, you can't work, even if you were recently admitted in TN status.

Comment: So, is the purpose of the B visa to allow you clear exit immigration and/or get on a plane in passport B's country, rather than to actually enter the US? As long as you remain employed in the US I'm not sure it would be wise to use the B visa to enter the US since it might lead them to want to cancel the TN (which depends on your continued employment).

Comment: @TomasBy it might be possible, but if that's the case it would probably be necessary to get the B visa before beginning the TN application, because the consulate is unlikely to approve a B visa for someone who doesn't intend to use it to enter the US.  I don't know whether a TN application would result in the cancellation of an existing B visa but I suppose it probably would not, especially if the B visa is valid for 5 or 10 years.  (The default validity of a B visa depends on the nationality of the traveler.)

Comment: @phoog yes the purpose is mainly to clear exit immigration of country B without too much hassle. I have a Canadian passport. But now that I think about it, it might not be possible to obtain a visa on passport B since the Canadian passport already gives visa-free admission rights.

Comment: "the purpose is mainly to clear exit immigration of country B": most countries don't pay any attention to your entry documents for your destination.  Are you certain that country B does pay attention to that?

Answer (score 4):

In comments, you mention that the work visa is a TN visa, and that one of your citizenships is Canadian.  In this case, you do not need a visa at all.  To enter the US in TN status as a Canadian, you present the relevant documents at the border.  Similarly, to enter in B status, you just show up at the border.  There is no reason to apply for a B visa beforehand.

You can certainly get a B visa in your non-Canadian passport, but it's a bit questionable to apply for one since you don't actually intend to use it to enter the US.  You will probably also have to explain why you want to use a B visa instead of your Canadian passport.  If you've already established yourself in the US in TN status, furthermore, you'll have to explain why you want to enter the US as a tourist, and how long you plan to stay there without working before you leave and re-enter to resume your employment in TN status.  It's mostly hard to imagine how this is less hassle than the hassle you would encounter leaving country B with your Canadian passport, or with your other passport lacking a B visa.

I say "mostly" because all of this leads me to suspect that your other passport is a country B passport, and country B prohibits dual nationality.  In that case, you might want to have a look at [I have two passports/nationalities. How do I use them when I travel?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/52100/19400)

Another possibility is that your other passport is visa-free in country B and your Canadian passport is not.  In that case, there is no reason to hide your Canadian citizenship from country B.  Just use your other passport there, but check in to your flight to the US with your Canadian passport (showing both passports whenever you need to demonstrate both your status in country B and your ability to enter the US without a visa).